# django static_root understanding - IOError - ??

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

i am trying to use some image in my views.py, i did this,

```
from django.conf import settings
image = settings.STATIC_ROOT + "images/test.png"
fp = open(image, 'rb')
```

but it is saying:

```
IOError at / 
(2, 'No such file or directory')
```

in my settings.py, i have:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

what do i miss here ? `STATICFILES_DIRS` is empty but in templates, i has been working till now, but now i want to get image in my views.py.

Comment: The `STATIC_ROOT` should ends with a `/`. `os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "static/")`

Comment: @AamirAdnan, does that make difference?

Comment: Yes i think so. Assume settings.STATIC_ROOT = '/abc/static' so right now your path would be `settings.STATIC_ROOT + "images/test.png"` = `/abc/staticimages/test.png` but it should be `/abc/static/images/test.png`

Comment: @AamirAdnan, nope, not helping

Comment: Try printing out `STATIC_ROOT` might be a chance `PROJECT_PATH` is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve
serve(request, 'images/test.png')
```

If memory serves me correct tho this will only work if debug is true.

But it sounds like its not finding the path, to find te project path...

**`Print(normpath(join(dirname(__file__), '..')))`**

This should help you identify and correct the problem.

Comment: can you pls explain how to use this command and where to use it.

Comment: just add print(normpath(join(dirname(__file__), '..'))) in your view if you like and in your terminal output it will print out. print("hello") etc just outputs.

Comment: normpath, join, dirname are all showing error being undefined variable

Comment: @doniyor: You have to import them from `os.path`.

Comment: How did you get on with this?